# Generated types in Prisma do not have optional fields as defined in the schema

Tags: orm, prisma, prisma2

Using Prisma v 3.8.1

My `User` Model is

```
model User {
  id                   Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt            DateTime?    @default(now())
  email                String       @unique
  name                 String       
  password             String
  accessToken          String?
  accessTokenCreatedAt DateTime?    @default(now())
  address              String?
  city                 String?
  state                String?
  postalCode           String?
  phoneNumber          Int?
  igUserId             String?
  role                 Role         @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id])
  roleId               Int
  organization         Organization? @relation(fields: [organizationId], references: [id])
  organizationId       Int?
  orders               Order[]
}
```

Generated type is

```
type User = {
    id: number;
    createdAt: Date | null;
    email: string;
    name: string;
    password: string;
    accessToken: string | null;
    accessTokenCreatedAt: Date | null;
    address: string | null;
    city: string | null;
    state: string | null;
    postalCode: string | null;
    phoneNumber: number | null;
    igUserId: string | null;
    roleId: number;
    organizationId: number | null;
}
```

There are no optional fields in this type as described in the model, not even for the autogenerated id field. So while using this type in my code, I keep getting this error

```
Type '{ name: any; email: any; password: string; roleId: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'User': id, createdAt, accessToken, accessTokenCreatedAt, and 7 more.
```

Expected behaviour: Optional fields should be marked optional ? in the generated typescript Types so that its easy in the code to only set the required fields and pass it to .create() method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type is not intended to use with `create` or similar methods. It's return type of `find*` methods and such. It's supposed to match DB table and table does not have undefined or optional rows, only nullable or not.

If you look carefully you can find other types, for example, `UserCreateArgs` with `data` property which will be used for `create` method. And that type has optional fields exactly how you want it to be.

What I don't understand is where you got this error from? Have you tried to use the types for your own wrappers?

Comment: I am trying to create a new User using the prisma.user.create(). to pass the data, I have declared a variable user: User (here User is a prisma generated Type for my model). At the time I am only setting the 3 required fields, but typescript is asking me to set the other optional fields too at the compile time.

Comment: Yep, that's incorrect. You need to use `UserCreateArgs["data"]` for that, as I wrote in the answer

Comment: I'm trying the same thing, but those don't seem to be importable in ones project. They are in the 100s of lines of auto-generated code but somehow exported *within* the PrismaClient class in such a way I can't import. Any hints on how to get at them?

Comment: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/11927